# No WebBrowser Control in Toolbox Winforms .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a recommended workaround for that missing web browser element?
In the old Winforms (until .NET FW 4.8), it was found in the toolbox.

Comment: Install the nuget package with `WebView2`. That's the replacement for WebBrowser. It uses Microsoft Edge to render.

Comment: Or... if this is a new project, you could build everything in MAUI for a cross platform UI. With either BlazorWebView / WebView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Poul Bak said. The solution is to search for webview2 in nuget, and then install it. The webview2 control will appear in the toolbox, and then drag and drop.Microsoft's official documentation  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms).Hope it helps you.

Comment: Ok so this the new way to do it. But I also managed to use the WebBrowser by initializing it in the code. Its missing in the toolbox in .NET 5+ but the old one is still there. I need to migrate some old winforms so its good to have the 2 options. TY

Comment: Here's a official documentation link in English, if you prefer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/webview2-api-reference?tabs=dotnet

Comment: Man, You're a life saver! I was looking for a good and "light" web control that supports new html and script features (without the script errors that Windows.Forms WebBrowser Control has) to work with for this hole year and this WebView2 worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a reference from Microsoft for you, but I believe webbrowser is not available in .NET 5+. You'd need to switch to webview2, which uses chromium Edge.

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a new object 'WebBrowser' in your code and if it is recognizable you can add the controller 'WebBrowser' using code like:

```
    Dim wbBr As New WebBrowser
    wbBr.ObjectForScripting = Me
    wbBr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Me.Controls.Add(wbBr)
```